# Android how to read a text file stored in assets which contains spanish characters

Tags: android, eclipse, character-encoding, android-assets

I have a JSON file in the *assets* folder which contains some data with spanish characters.

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name" : "NÚMERO DE REFERENCIA",
      "type": "numeric"
    },
    {
      "name" : "FECHA DE VENCIMIENTO",
      "type": "date"
    },
    {
      "name" : "MONTO",
      "type": "money"
    },
  ]
}
```

I read the first `"name" : "NÚMERO DE REFERENCIA"`, using:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

But I get the character "Ò".

I have tested using "ISO-8859-1", but worse, I get a "?" symbol.

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the character encoding of your file to `UTF-8`.

And then just read your file like that, without specifying the encoding:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Comment: How can I change the encoding of my file?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Right click the Project -- Properties and select Resource on the left side menu. You may have to do the same for your asset file.

Comment: I could change the encoding only the properties of the file and it worked. Thanks a lot!